Relationship Between Gini Index and Decision Trees
I am trying to learn about the mathematics behind how Decision Tree algorithms work  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning).
For example (and for simplicity sake), consider a dataset with categorical predictors $x_1, x_2, ... x_n$ and binary response variable $y$ (e.g. yes/no).
I am trying to understand how the Gini Impurity algorithm works. I tried to read the Wikipedia page and here is my understanding.
Gini Impurity:
For any of the $x_i$ variables, we can make binary splits based on the available categories. For example, if $x_1$ has categories A, B, C - We can make binary groups (A vs BC), (B vs AC) and (C vs BA). If a variable has $k$ types of objects, here are the number of potential splits that can be made:
$$\sum_{r=1}^{k-1} \binom{k}{r} = 2^k - 2$$
Next, we define the Gini Impurity as $G(p)$, where $p$ is the proportion of items in the node that belong to the positive class (e.g., 'yes'). The Gini impurity is given by:
$$G(p) = 2p(1-p)$$
Here is my attempt to justify this formula: If we randomly select an item from the set, the probability that it belongs to the 'yes' class is $p$, and the probability that it belongs to the 'no' class is $1-p$.
If we then randomly assign a class label according to the distribution of labels in the set, the probability of misclassification is:

For an item that actually belongs to the 'yes' class: $p*(1-p)$
For an item that actually belongs to the 'no' class: $(1-p)*p$

Assuming we are equally likely to pick an item from either class, the overall probability of misclassification (i.e., the Gini impurity) is the average of these two probabilities:
$$G(p) = 1/2 * [2p*(1-p) + 2p*(1-p)] = 2p*(1-p)$$
Mathematically, this formula shows us that the Gini impurity is:

Low Purity: $2p*(1-p)$, which reaches its maximum value of 0.5 when $p=0.5$ (i.e., the set is equally divided between the two classes)
High Purity: its minimum value of 0 when $p=0$ or $p=1$ (i.e., all items belong to the same class)

Now, for each predictor $x_i$ with $k_i$ categories, we consider all possible splits. For each split, we partition the items into two groups, and calculate the Gini impurity for each group. The proportions of items that end up in the left and right nodes as $p_L$ and $p_R$, and the Gini impurities of these nodes as $G_L$ and $G_R$. The average Gini impurity of the split is then:
$$G_{avg} = p_L G_L + p_R G_R$$
Then, for all the data points that "survived" and were placed in the node below as a result from the split ...We then repeat this process for all possible splits of all predictors (within the surviving data), and choose the split that minimizes $G_{avg}$ , i.e. impurity of a potential split of all data points within the current node vs overall impurity of all data points within the current node:
$$\min_{i, s} \left[ p_{L,i,s} G_{L,i,s} + p_{R,i,s} G_{R,i,s} \right]$$
where the minimum is taken over all predictors $i$ and all possible splits $s$ of each predictor. This predictor is then removed from all future selections.
We then repeat this at each turn in the remaining variables for a greedy splitting rule. Intuitively, I understand this : Using Gini Impurity, we try to keep the Decision Tree as "pure" as possible.
Have I understood all this correctly?

You might be more likely to get an answer on https://stats.stackexchange.com/, since they specialize in data science.
